# How do I get my test extension working on other sites?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I just finished this tutorial to create my very first extension: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

However, the extensions only works on developer.chrome.com (because of some code "....pageUrl: {hostEquals: 'developer.chrome.com'},....")

How do I get it to run on other sites? (I want to use the extension for Google Docs, by the way)

I tried just changing the URL in the code but it didn't work

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43030019/10415043) will help you

Comment: Make sure 1) you've reloaded the extension, 2) you used the same syntax for the host name and didn't add any `*` or `https://` and so on - as you can see in the documentation for declarativeContent there are lots of dedicated properties. 3) Anyway we can't really help without seeing the code and manifest.json.